# How to code on below coding scenario in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

```
02-Jan-20 Success
03-Jan-20 Failed
04-Jan-20 Failed
05-Jan-20 Success
06-Jan-20 Success
07-Jan-20 Success
08-Jan-20 Failed
```

Need the below o/p:

```
02-Jan   02-Jan Success
03-Jan   04-Jan Fail
05-Jan   07-Jan Success
08-Jan   08-Jan Fail
```

Please help  me with the python code

Thank you .

Regards

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide the code with attempts you've made to resolve this problem, and whatever output that code produced.

Comment: what are you asking here? what logic is suppose to be applied to get that output?

Comment: The logic is just to aggregate the series of successes or failures into one line with beginning and end dates. For example, from Jan 5 to Jan 7 were successes, so `05-Jan 07-Jan Success` is what it gets reduced to. @OP, please make an attempt to code a solution first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code snippet,

```
a = [["02-Jan-20", "Success"],["03-Jan-20", "Failed"],["04-Jan-20", "Failed"],["05-Jan-20", "Success"],["06-Jan-20", "Success"],
     ["07-Jan-20", "Success"],["08-Jan-20", "Failed"]]

df = pd.DataFrame(a,columns=["Date","Status"])
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])

df["lag"] = df.Status.shift(-1)
df["lag"].fillna(df["Status"],inplace=True)
df["diff"] = df["Status"] != df["lag"]

df["Cum"] = df["diff"].shift(1)
df["Cum"].fillna(df["diff"],inplace=True)
df["Cumsum"] = df["Cum"].cumsum()

df_n = df.groupby(["Status","Cumsum"]).agg(Date_From = ("Date",min), Date_To = ("Date",max)).reset_index().sort_values("Date_From")[["Date_From","Date_To","Status"]]

df_n["Date_From"] = df_n.Date_From.dt.strftime("%d-%b")
df_n["Date_To"] = df_n.Date_To.dt.strftime("%d-%b")

print(df_n)
```

Answer (score 0):

@ Saravanakumar,

Thank you appreciate the code! Looks great.

I tried replicating in the SQL tables as below:

select b.start_date,a.end_date from
(select run_Date as end_date, rownum as seq from (select lead,lag ,case when nvl(lead,0)<> status then 0 else 1 end  cond
, run_date,status from (select run_date,status,lead(status) over (order by run_Date) as lead, lag(status) over (order by run_Date) as lag from hr.W_STATUS_F order by 1))where cond=0)a,

(select run_date as start_date,ROWNUM as seq from
(select run_date,rownum,case when nvl(previous_status,0)<>status then 0 else 1 end cond from (select run_date,status,lag(status) over (order by run_Date) previous_status from hr.W_STATUS_F)
)where cond=0)b
where a.seq=b.seq;